# Jacobian in the transformation of variables

Tags: integration, transformation, jacobian

I have an integral and I want to transform it using the substitution
$u = x^2 - 2y^2$ and $v = xy$.
I'm having trouble finding the jacobian, because when I make $x$ and $y$ the subject, I get really complicated roots, and was thinking there might be a fast way to find the jacobian of this.

Wondering if anyone has an idea.

Comment: If your integral has variables $x$ and $y$ and your substitution is $ u = ...$, $v = ...$, then you can simply find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, and find the determinant of that matrix. Then, your Jacobian will be the reciprocal value of that determinant, i.e. the determinant of the inverse matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Why is this true? So if $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ then the jacobian of $x,y$ is the inverse matrix of the jacobian of $u,v$?

Comment: Because the substitution $(x, y) \mapsto (x^2-2y^2, xy)$ is a diffeomorphism, and the complicated expressions you got are its inverse, so their derivatives (i.e. Jacobian matrices) are also inverses to each other (by the inverse function theorem, I think; don't quote me on this).

Comment: Holy moly. I just realised this. Thanks, we learnt the Inverse Function Theorem a while back. Is this a valid proof?  
 let $f\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x^2 - 2y^2 \\ xy \end{pmatrix}$, then the determinant of the jacobian of $f$ is $2x^2 + 4y^2$ is non-zero for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Hence, the Jacobian of $f$ is invertible, by the inverse function theorem there is a local $C^1$ inverse around every point other than $(0,0)$. And so for the inverse mapping $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}$,

Comment: ... the inverse of the jacobian of $f$ at $(u,v)$ is the jacobian of the inverse mapping $f^{-1}$ at $(x,y)$??

Comment: That would be it. So the Jacobian you're looking for is $\frac{1}{2x^2+4y^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, so just to make sure, the method of finding the inverse is only valid iff the jacobian of $u,v$ is invertible, yes (or rather, throughout our required region of integration)?

Comment: Yes, that condition is there to ensure the derivative (which is a linear mapping) is bijective, so that we can apply the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Much appreciated! Liking how the two connected to each other